# ASP CLASSIC run 100% on ASP.NET server?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have an internal website in ASP CLASSIC working in my local server (third party host company).

The company now wants to put all sites on your central server - and cut all "3rd party hosts"

Then, I receive a memo from IS - "Our Server supports only ASP.NET and SQL SERVER"

My website will run 100% on this server?

or I need to reprogram in ASP.NET?

tks!

Comment: I suggest you ask your IS team to add support for ASP Classic, or have the people that told you to get rid of 3rd party hosts speak to them. If the consensus is that they won't do it, then you'll need to reimplement. But it's definitely possible to host ASP Classic on a server that also has ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the settings of new server and you have to ask server administrators.

Here is a guide to activating ASP support on IIS:

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

(Also they may have to consider supporting 32 bits applications if you have problem connecting to databases)

Comment: The problem connecting to databases relates to ODBC and OLEDB drivers which are 32/64 bit specific.  I would also caution that ASP 3.0 is not something you'd want to run unless required to and very much not in a public-facing fashion given security implications of a 16 year old technology.